# Install vim without root privilege

Tags: vim, root, ncurses

There are several posts on the internet about this, but I haven't found a suitable solution for my case.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Download vim
- `./configure` gives

```
 You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
 Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

- tried to install ncurses but when `make` I run into

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling /usr/bin/gcc
gnatmake: *** link failed.
```

- I've actually found out that in the system there are

```
/usr/lib64/libncurses.so
/usr/lib64/libncursesw.so
```

so I've tried to play around with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH, but to no avail.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Your system has the run-time ncurses libraries that allows ncurses-dependent programs to execute. You do not have the development materials (header files) required to build such programs against ncurses. Your GNU/Linux distro, if that's what you're using, probably provides some `ncurses-dev` package or whatever. If you don't have the privilege to do that, then you have to build our own installation of `ncurses` from scratch in your local environment. You have to pass the correct `--prefix` to all the `configure` scripts so the builds don't try to install into `/usr/local`.

Comment: I've tried something like `./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local` before `make` in the ncurses directory I've downloaded, but I still get that gnatlink error. I don't know if that's what you were suggesting trying

Comment: Try this https://superuser.com/questions/162560/how-to-install-vim-on-linux-when-i-dont-have-root-permissions

Comment: `gnatlink` is something related to the GNU Ada compiler (Gnat). It seems that ncurses bundles some support for Ada, and has done that since 1995. Maybe it's trying to build that. Maybe ncurses has configure options which disable building anything related to Ada? That would be very reasonable.

Comment: found it ! I'll answer my question then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guessed by Kaz in the comment above, ncurses does have the `--without-ada` option in its `./configure` to disable the Ada build. This allowed me to install ncurses and consequently vim !

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd mention an alternative solution.

Neovim provides pre-built packages which you could simply download and run. Follow instructions from their [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/).

Now, Neovim is a vim-fork, so you wouldn't be getting the "original" vim.
But, they are very similar, and the install process is a lot simpler.

Comment: another alternative solution: if you use anaconda you could just do:

`conda install -c conda-forge vim` 

source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/vim